# Pause code and wait for input java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm taking beginning programming for school at the moment, and am trying to improve on an assignment I have already completed. What I want to do is request from the user x amount of times some information and put that information in an `ArrayList` the problem is that I need to wait until the user has input information using `Scanner` before the code can continue but it attempts to continue anyways and I get an out of bounds error.

```
class Marbles {
    private static List _colors = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static List _numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private static Scanner _input;

    Marbles(Scanner input) {
        _input = input;
        int marbleCount = getMarbleCount(); // => 5
        int marbleIndex = 0;

        //If you don't want to play, that's okay too.

        if (marbleCount == 0) {
            System.out.print("Goodbye!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //populate the marble arrays
        for (; marbleCount > 0; marbleCount--) {

            String color;
            Integer numberOfMarbles;
            //Count the marbles up from 1 to display out
            int currentMarble = marbleIndex + 1;
            //current index to fill the arrays
            System.out.printf("Color for marble %d: ", currentMarble);
            color = _input.nextLine();

            //it should pause here but it isn't

            System.out.printf("Number of %s marbles: ", _colors.get(marbleIndex));

            _colors.add(color);
            _numbers.add(currentMarble);
            marbleIndex++;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're printing `_colors.get(marbleIndex)` before you store the color in the `_colors` list. That's why you get that exception. It has nothing to do with pauses.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I just wasn't seeing it.